# Amount of overlaps per minute

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to make an SQL-Statement in order to find the amount of users that are using a channel by date and time. Let me give you an example:

Let's call this table Data:

```
Date        Start   End 
01.01.2020  17:00   17:30   
01.01.2020  17:01   17:03   
01.01.2020  17:29   18:30
```

Data is a table that shows when an user started the connection on a channel and the time the connection was closed. A connection can be made any time, which means from 00:00 until the next day.

What I am trying to achieve is to count the maximum number of connections that were made over a big period if time. Let's say 1st February to 1st April.

My idea was to make another table with timestamps in Excel. The table would display a Timestamp for every Minute in a specific date.

Then I tried to make a statement like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Data,Timestamps
WHERE Timestamps.Time BETWEEN Data.Start AND Data.End.
```

Now logically this statement does what is supposed to do. The only problem is that it is not really performant and therefore not finishing. With the amount of timestamps and the amount of data I have to check it is not able to finish.

Could anybody help me with this problem? Any other ideas I can try or how to improve my statement?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

So why dou you create another table in Excel and not directly in MS Access and then why won't you set up the indexes of the timestamps right. That will speed it up by factors.

By the way I think that your statement will print repeat every user that happened to match your Start .. End period, so the amount of rows produced will be enormous. You shall rather try

```
SELECT Timestamps.Time, COUNT(*) 
FROM Data,Timestamps
WHERE Timestamps.Time BETWEEN Data.Start AND Data.End
GROUP BY Timestamps.Time;
```

But sorry if the syntax in MS Access is different.

Comment: Because of the auto-complete function in Excel that I could not do in Access. I needed in form of 01.01.2020 00:00, 01.01.2020 00:01 etc. for every minute and day.

Where is the difference between your statement and mine besides the selected fields? 

I will try to index the timestamps tomorrow and see if that helped, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well then import the table you created in Excel into a proper MS Access table. That is always loads faster than processing external table. The proposed query is a `GROUP BY` query so you get just the timestamp value and the summary amount of users at a given moment, much less data if you have loads of users. You have stated that you want to *find the amount of users* at a given moment. You can try with a shorter timespan - say days or just few hours and you can fine tune your query first like that to see the difference and fine tune the output of your query.

Comment: I already did that, I might have described the situation wrongly. I did also have the same Query as you and as I was saying it is working, but just not efficient for every data. However I need it to be every minute and therefore a little more efficient.

Comment: Tune your indexes and if it doesn't improve the performace, you can try another database engine where you can increase the size of your key cache or write a piece of code, that will do the counting without relying on relational algebra. Even writing a VBA procedure in Access might suffice. You are basically matching every record in your connection data with every record in the timestamps table and depending on the number of recs in your Data table, this can be costly. You have not mentioned what query execution time would you deem acceptable. GL.

Comment: *However I need it to be every minute* - you intend to run that query every minute ?